# IOS user experience for allowing user to change map type

Tags: ios, selection, maps

I am learning Google Map SDK and I would like to allow the customer to change the map's type.

I thought that making a drop down list is helpful, but I see that Apple doesn't make a drop down list but it makes a picker instead.

What is the best user experience approach to allow users to selects the map's type?

I have chosen this:

[image: Map with button menu for type selection]

Is this the best UX for this interaction? Is there another pattern that would be better?

#### Edit

I see that storyboard just allows me to add one item bar at the right, so it seems that my choice is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, adding a UIToolbar underneath the navigation bar and have those segmented controls in it would be appropriate. This actually takes up a bit of space on the MapView as you place the UIToolbar on the MapView but that would actually look a lot better on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the segment control can go to bottom area of screen just like the following screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have space to show all available options and indicate which option is currently selected (as you have done), then this is the best user experience. There is no need to change what you have done in the screen shot.